# Simplest way to create a threadpool in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, threadpool

Would the simplest way to create a threadpool (or, at least obtain the code for a working one) be from C++11?

I have a problem accessing libraries from work, I am having problems getting hold of C++11 compiler. Would it be easier/harder finding a threadpool example from boost? I may be able to get the boost libraries installed. If not, I will have to try and find a way to get C++11 compiler.

(In case anybody is wondering why I am asking, I have VS2010 installed, but that has no C++11 and I cannot update cygwin due to work restrictions on TCP ports).

Comment: What do you want the threadpool to do?  Is there more than executing tasks on a pool of threads?

Comment: As a minor detail, VS2010 has part of C++11 and most of the library parts. Double-check first - for example, it does support lambdas.

Comment: This is on Windows I assume? Do you need portability, or can you just program with the classic win32?

Comment: There is this simple library -> https://code.google.com/p/threadpool11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++11 doesn't have anything particular for thread pooling built in to it.  I think you want Boost-based [threadpool](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/) implementation.